# Limiting access to Wordpress login through the .htaccess file is not blocking anyone

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ip

I have been trying to edit the rules for my Wordpress site through the .htaccess file. I've tried several different options with no luck. My goal is to make the wp-login.php page accessible only to a certain list of IP addresses. Each method I've tried results in no change, meaning even if I put in a bogus IP address as the only one to be allowed access, I can still get to the page from any device.

These are the methods I have tried:

Adding this to the root .htaccess file

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
</Files>
```

And this to the wp-admin .htaccess file

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I've also tried this in the wp-admin .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "WordPress Admin Access Control"
AuthType Basic
<LIMIT GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
# whitelist IP address
allow from xx.xx.xx.xxx
</LIMIT>
```

This option in the root .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN wp-admin restriction based on IP address
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
# END IP restriction
```

I'm not very familiar with .htaccess rules. Each of these options was tried at the beginning and the end of the files. The only other code in the file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that ran into this issue. I was never able to get the .htaccess file to work. I tried adding the access rules to the web.config file and had some issues there as well, however I eventually found a way to add access rules through the IIS Manager using IP Address and Domain Restrictions. I did have to install that feature as it wasn't in my list of options right away however it worked right away and I noticed that after installing it, making changes to my web.config file also started working.